# how do we create tabgroup inside tab in titanium

Tags: titanium-alloy

Hello I have basic two tab which is located on bottom side of application. I want to create another tabgroup when I clicked on second tab. I am searching a lot, but only able to add tab in existing tabgroup. My application requirement is when I clicked on second tab of existing tabgroup another tabgroup should be created and it should appears at the top of the same window.please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you cannot add that.
if you work to develop android apps. do with tabGroup and actionBar or MenuBar

you can search the API here :

actionBar : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar

menuBar : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Menu

Answer (score 0):

From the api doc for tabgroup

> On Android, only one tab group may exist at one time. A tab group may
>   be closed to allow a new one to be opened later, but the root of the
>   application must be a heavyweight window to prevent it exiting. Tabs
>   cannot be removed from the tab group once added, and tabs cannot be
>   reordered.
>
> On iOS, more than one tab group may exist, and may be opened and
>   closed as required. Each tab can contain a stack of windows, and the
>   user can switch between them by tapping the tab's associated control.
>   Tabs can be removed, and the user may (optionally) be allowed to
>   reorder tabs.